# What does the + do in $+commands[...]?

Tags: zsh

Here's another question that is impossible to search for: how to interpret `$+commands[foobar]`?  I assume that it is a variant of `$commands[foobar]`, but who knows.  (With zsh, at least **I** never know.)

I'd also like to know how one would search for the answer to this question, either in the zsh documentation or online.

Comment: Give a real example with real commands, maybe? Try looking at regex examples, Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was documented under [Parameter Expansion section in zsh documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion):

```
${+name}
  If name is the name of a set parameter ‘1’ is substituted, otherwise ‘0’
  is substituted.
```

Example:

```
$ unset foo
$ if (( $+foo )); then echo set; else echo not set; fi
not set
$ foo=1
$ if (( $+foo )); then echo set; else echo not set; fi
set
```

In `$+commands[foobar]`, `zsh` check if the name return by `$commands[foobar]` is a set parameter.

Comment: Ah, so the `{ ... }` are optional??????

Comment: @kjo: Yes, as documented in `${name}` part of `Parameter Expansion`: `any of the characters '^', '=', '~', '#' or '+' appearing before the name, all of which work with or without braces`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer about `${+name}` variable expansion basically solves the problem.

I just wanna add some info about the speed comparison to complete the topic. The reason why `(($+commands[tree]))` style command is used is that, searching commands in an array is faster than `command -v tree`, `which -a tree`.

```bsh
❯ export TIMEFMT=$'%U user %S system %P cpu %*E total'

❯ time (for i ({1..100}) if (($+commands[tree])); then echo 1 &>/dev/null; fi)
0.00s user 0.00s system 89% cpu 0.006 total

❯ time (for i ({1..100}) if command -v tree &>/dev/null; then echo 1 &>/dev/null; fi)
0.00s user 0.00s system 95% cpu 0.010 total

❯ time (for i ({1..100}) if which -a tree &>/dev/null; then echo 1 &>/dev/null; fi)
0.01s user 0.01s system 97% cpu 0.021 total
```